# Button gets pushed down when decreasing the browsers width

Tags: html, css

I have a div that has three elements in it a label, an input box, and a button. they each have 30 percent for their width, so they should become smaller when resizing the browser, but the button gets pushed down at some point. Here is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="height: 100%; margin: 0">
<head>
<title></title>

</head>
<body style="height: 100%; margin: 0">

<div style="width: 30%; height: 20%;  background-color:red; text-align: center; ">
<label style="height: 80%; width: 30%; display: inline-block;">Table No: </label>
<input style="height: 80%; width: 30%" type="text" name="">
<button style="height: 80%; width: 30%">Back</button>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

how can I prevent the button from getting pushed down?

Comment: You can set the display of div to flex to prevent button from wrapping down, like `display:flex;`

Comment: @GagandeepSingh thanks It solved my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applying `display:flex;` or `display:inline-flex;` (depending your purpose) to your parent `<div>` will solve your problem. However, I highly recommend you restructuring the layout and considering using [media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) for it. In the case of small size screens you can have `width:100%;` for your parent `<div>` and for larger screen sizes `width:30%;` as you have right now. Media queries are a better option for making your website responsive than just relying on CSS percentage.

Comment: Thanks that solved my problem. I haven't used media queries before, but I will look into it.

Comment: @AraKawa consider also avoiding inline-styling. It's better to keep your html and CSS separate from each other. Also using height in percentage isn't a good practice for the case you have. There aren't so many case when you really need it

Comment: thanks for advice the code I wrote here is just a simplified version of what I'm working on. I have css files  for almost every section of my code. As for the height percentage can you elaborate on why it is not a good practice?